# Spin-1/2 with expectation values other than $\hbar/2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin, spinors

I came across a problem that is related to the expectation value of spin-1/2. 
Assuming I want to find a single (or possibly a set of) spin state(s) $$\lvert\psi\rangle$$ that gives me an expectation value of say,

$$
\langle\psi\rvert Sx\lvert\psi\rangle = \pm\hbar/4
$$
$$
\langle\psi\rvert Sy\lvert\psi\rangle = \pm\hbar/4
$$
$$ 
\langle\psi\rvert Sz\lvert\psi\rangle = \pm\hbar/4 
$$

How should I approach this problem. Is it still a simple superposition of eigenspinors or does it require spin coupling?

Comment: You should be able to solve it with a superposition of eigenspinors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Representing the spin state as a spinor $$\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}.$$ $a$ and $b$ are in general complex numbers and obey the normalization condition $$|a|^2 + |b|^2=1,$$ so that leaves three independent parameters to define your spin state.

Writing the spin operators in their matrix form each of your above written equations becomes an equation for $a$ and $b$. Hence you have three equations with three unknowns and can solve for the spin state.

Comment: This is what I thought. Thank you. I will do some calculus and come back here.